# How to parse a sprintf string in PHP

Tags: php, string, parsing, printf

Consider a typical structure created by `sprintf` as

```
$pattern = "%1$s-%2$s|%3$s";
$str = sprintf($pattern, $a, $b, $c);
```

now we have a string as `test-fore|here`

How we can parse the latter string by using the **`sprintf` pattern** to get the values of `$a`, `$b`, and `$c`.

Comment: `sscanf` is the dedicated analog to `(s)printf`, but whether the exact same pattern will work is questionable, depending on the values of the variables.

Comment: `sscanf` delimits strings by whitespace

Comment: @OneTrickPony Say what now?

Comment: $pattern = "%1s-%2d-%3s"; works

Comment: @shin no specific pattern, I am looking for a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt using regular expressions:

```
function sscanfAlt($format, $str){

  // split string by %s, %d, %2$s etc.
  // note that this regex doesn't handle some identifiers
  // like precision or padding
  $parts = preg_split('/(%(?:\d\$)?[bcdeEufFgGosxX])/', $format, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

  // odd entries = format directives; even entries = normal text
  foreach($parts as $idx => &$value)
    $value = ($idx & 1) ? preg_quote($value, '/') : '(.*)';

  // rebuild as regex
  preg_match('/' . implode('', $parts) . '/', $str, $matches);
  array_shift($matches);
  return $matches;
}
```

Use like:

```
$values = sscanfAlt('%1$s-%2$s|%3$s', 'test-fore|here');
```